# Shuffling and drawing from a deck of cards in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user to shuffle or draw from a deck of cards. I'm running into a problem with this:

```
shuffle(deck);    
draw(deck);
```

It says this is the problem:

```
invalid method declaration; return type required
shuffle(deck);   
^
Deck.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
shuffle(deck);   
        ^
```

Here's the whole code (I edited it after some comments -- I am still having trouble with it, though):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Deck {

    String[] number = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String[] suit = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
    String[] deck = new String[52];
    int cardsUsed = 0;

    public void main(String[] args) {

        Deck d = new Deck();
        // print d. 
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
                deck[13 * j + i] = number[i] + " of " + suit[j];

            }
        }

        while (true) ;
        System.out.println("shuffle, draw, print, sort, cut");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        String command = s.next();
        if (command.equals(shuffle)) {
            d.shuffle();
        } else if (command.equals(draw)) {
            d.draw();
        } else if (command.equals(print)) {
            d.print();
        } else if (command.equals(sort)) {
            d.sort();
        } else if (command.equals(cut)) ;
        {
            d.cut();
        }
        s.close();
        shuffle(deck);
        draw(deck);

    }

    public void shuffle() {
        int k;
        Random shuffle = new Random();
        for (k = deck.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            int index = Math.abs((shuffle.nextInt()) % 52);
            String temp = deck[k];
            deck[k] = deck[index];
            deck[index] = temp;
        }
        int l;
        for (l = 0; l < deck.length; l++) {
            System.out.println(deck[l]);

        }
    }

    public void draw() {
        System.out.print(deck[cardsUsed]);
        // for (int cardsUsed = 0; i < deck.length; cardsUsed++) {   
        // return deck.length - cardsUsed; 
        if (cardsUsed < deck.length) {
            System.out.print(deck[cardsUsed]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No cards are left in the deck.");
            cardsUsed++;
            // return deck[cardsUsed - 1];   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting so it will be easier to read

Comment: Looks like you are missing curly braces after `while(true)`.

Comment: Neither your shuffle nor draw methods take a `String[]` as an input.  You also cannot call them before the deck has been initialized outside of your main method.

Comment: You call shuffle(deck); ... and definition of shuffle requires no arguments?? public void shuffle() { ... }

Comment: while (true); is an infinite loop, the next line will never be reached.

Comment: You've edited this question once or twice; I only reverted to the earliest occurrence.  My advice would be to not continually edit the question, as that may invalidate earlier, existing, valid answers.

Answer (score 2):

Statements belong in method/constructor bodies, but you have these method calls outside of any method:

```
shuffle(deck);    
draw(deck);
```

Move them inside a method or constructor.

In addition, those methods have no parameters; either add the parameter to the methods or remove them from the calls.

In addition, this line is an infinite loop and needs to be fixed:

```
while (true);
```

You will need to remove that semicolon, and depending on your intended `while` loop body, place the appropriate braces.

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration for `shuffle` and `draw` have no parameters, but when you call them, you are passing in `deck`

Also you should move the calls into the `main` function

Answer (score 0):

Code wouldn't compile.  Made it compile.  But I don't think its doing what you want, as others have suggested you need to fix the infinite loop.

Here is the compileable code to work off of... should get you going a bit quicker here.

As others have mentioned, remove the shuffle(deck) and draw(deck) lines at the top.  As well you needed a static main.  Also bracket issues.  Take this as a starting point.  It runs.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Deck
{

static String [] number =
{
    "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"
}
;

static String [] suit =
{
    "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"
}
;

static String [] deck = new String[52];

int cardsUsed = 0;



public static void main (String [] args)
{


    Deck d = new Deck();

    for (int i = 0;
    i&lt;
    number.length;
    i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0;
        j&lt;
        suit.length;
        j++)
        {

            deck[13*j+i] = number[i] + " of " + suit[j];



        }


    }


    while (true)
    {

        System.out.println ("shuffle or draw");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("What would you like to do?");

        String command = s.next( );

        if (command.equals("shuffle"))
        {

            d.shuffle();


        }
        else if (command.equals("draw"))
        {

            d.draw();


        }

        s.close();

    }



}


public void shuffle ()
{

    int k;

    Random shuffle = new Random();

    for (k = deck.length-1;
    k &gt;
    = 0;
    k--)
    {

        int index = Math.abs((shuffle.nextInt())%52);

        String temp = deck[k];

        deck[k] = deck[index];

        deck[index] = temp;


    }

    int l;

    for (l = 0;
    l&lt;
    deck.length;
    l++)
    {

        System.out.println (deck[l]);



    }


}


public void draw ()
{

    System.out.print (deck[cardsUsed]);

    if (cardsUsed &lt;
    deck.length)
    {

        System.out.print (deck[cardsUsed]);


    }
    else
    {

        System.out.println ("No cards are left in the deck.");

        cardsUsed++;



    }


}
```

}